# What's the maximum end date value for bloomberg intraday request

Tags: bloomberg, trading

What's the maximum *end date* value for bloomberg market data provider api for requesting intradays?

if I send an end date from 2099 year I get a rejection with *InvalidBusiness* datetime exception

Comment: Why would you want an end date greater than today?

Comment: It's a default value for empty end-time. (like DateTime.Max)
There is no valid reason for having end date greater than today, but in the same time you should get same trades for today or for tomorrow as end date.